# How to pass a 2-dimensional Vector to a function in rust?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to pass a 2-d array to a function but I cant figure out how to specify the expected type of the function.

My code looks like this

```rust
fn main() {
    let ker = vec![[-1, -1, -1], [-1, 8, -1], [-1, -1, -1]];

    do_schtuff(ker);
}

fn do_schtuff(k: Vec<Vec<i32>>) {
    println!("{:?}", k);
}
```

P.S.: I'm new to rust so any advice would be really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this a vector of arrays, a.k.a. `Vector<[i32; 3]>`?

Comment: FYI, the better way to have a two dimensional vector is to have a 1-dimensional vector with an API that let it use as a 2-dimensional one. I'm pretty sure that some crates exist to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually have a two dimensional vector there. You have a vector of integer arrays. You need to change your code to actually use a vector with integer vectors in it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let ker = vec![vec![-1, -1, -1], vec![-1, 8, -1], vec![-1, -1, -1]];     
    do_schtuff(ker);
}

fn do_schtuff(k: Vec<Vec<i32>>) {
    println!("{:?}", k);
}
```

Though it almost certainly would be better to not move the vector and give ownership to the `do_schtuff` function, but instead to pass the vector as a reference to a slice:

```rust
fn main() {
    let ker = vec![vec![-1, -1, -1], vec![-1, 8, -1], vec![-1, -1, -1]];     
    do_schtuff(&ker[..]);
}

fn do_schtuff(k: &[Vec<i32>]) {  // Note it is more idiomatic to use a slice.
    println!("{:?}", k);
}
```